# how to run DBMS_RULE_ADM

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Oracle 11.2.0.3

My instructions are

```
DBMS_RULE_ADM.GRANT_SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE(DBMS_RULE_ADM.CREATE_RULE_OBJ, '<schema_name>');
```

I tried to run them at sqlplus /as sysdba

but it tells me unknown command beginning DBMS_RULE

Is there a different way to run these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `EXEC[UTE]` or `BEGIN ... END ;`.

```
EXEC DBMS_RULE_ADM.GRANT_SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE(DBMS_RULE_ADM.CREATE_RULE_OBJ, '');
```

Or:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_RULE_ADM.GRANT_SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE(DBMS_RULE_ADM.CREATE_RULE_OBJ, '');
END;
/
```